# Dynamically added Select Box is not being posted

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "add_secondary_interest.php",
        data: "interest=ok", 
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $('#interest_table tr:last').after(html);
        }
});
```

The ajax response is this

```
<select name="test[]">                                            
<option value='7'>abc</option>
<option value='1'>xyz</option>
</select>
```

But when i post the form, this dynamic select box is not posted.

Comment: What are you expecting to see, and what are you seeing?  Your question does not make sense to me.

Comment: When i submit my form. this form element is being posted on another page.

Comment: It might be a little informative to expand your question for god's sake!

Comment: How should i link this select box with my page <form> element.

Comment: Do you see the `<select>` box after inserting it?

Comment: You want to post your form with jQuery?

Comment: Are you sure you are inserting the select box in the form ?

Comment: Show us the rest of your html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that, when jQuery adds the element, it gets bound to the table element rather than the form element. To fix this, make the DOM relative to the form. For example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "add_secondary_interest.php",
    data: "interest=ok", 
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
        $('form #interest_table tr:last').after(html); //<<<<<
    }}
```

Comment: **#interest_table tr:last** did not work at all. connor answer worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

right now you put the selectbox inside of a `<table>` but not inside of a `<td>` so its not visible.

Makr sure to add it to an existing `<td>` of a new one with you ajax request.

Comment: it is visible when i fire the click event. but it is not being posted to another page when i submit the form